# How to display date from string (format)

Tags: php

I have date (string):

```
2015-11-13T15:43:37+01:00
```

And I want to display this as "Y-m-d H:i:s" format. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can format your date with "date_format()"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php